# How do I rotate timeseries in a 5-d numpy matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-einsum

I am trying to rotate some seismic data held in a numpy nd-array. This array has dimensions (N-receiver, M-sources,3-source_channels, 3-receiver channels, K-time channels).

I know how to set up the rotation if applied to a single time stamp (t_i) over a single receiver & single source station. The actual Z, R, T, N, E, notation isn't important for the general problem, just know that the transformation is defined like so:

[image]

In python, for a single timestamp I'd probably code up something like:

```py
import numpy as np
a = 50.0 # example alpha
b = 130  # example beta
a_rotation = np.asarray([[1,0,0],[0,np.cos(a),np.sin(a)],[0,-np.sin(a),np.cos(a)]])
b_rotation = np.asarray([[1,0,0],[0,-np.cos(b),-np.sin(b)],[0,np.sin(b),-np.cos(b)]])

# pretend the zn's are actual float data
single_timeslice_data = np.asarray([[zz,zn,ze],[nz,nn,ne],[ez,en,ee]])

# operation w numpy matrix rotation

rotated_channels = a_rotation @ single_timeslice_data @ b_rotation
```

So my question is twofold:

1. How do I apply this matrix product with numpy over all timesteps?

ex: (3 x 3) * (3 x 3 x **K**) * (3 x 3)

2. How do I do this matrix product with numpy when there may be an arbitrary number of other dimensions?

ex: (3 x 3) * (**N** x **M** x 3 x 3 x **K**) * (3 x 3)

Comment: The basics of `@` is it does `dot`, matrix multiplication on the last 2 dimensions, and treats all the earlier ones as 'batch' dimensions, obeying the normal numpy broadcasting rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) 
(3 x 3) * (3 x 3 * K) * (3 * 3) = (3 x 3 x K)

```
np.einsum('ab,bcK,cd->adK', Arr1, Arr2, Arr3)
```

2) 
(3 x 3) * (N x M x 3 x 3 x K) * (3 x 3) = (N x M x 3 x 3 x K)

```
np.einsum('ab,NMbcK,cd->NMadK', Arr1, Arr2, Arr3)
```